# mlUnitTest throws a java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException at the end of the tests

Tags: unit-testing, marklogic, ml-gradle

I try to use mlunitTest with ml-gradle 3.17.1 and Marklogic marklogic-unit-test-client:1.0.0

All the tests are OK, I test with my test user on the UI and with ml-gradle.

But when ml-gradle wants to access the results in a directory `[build\test-results\marklogic-unit-test\TEST-{test-name}]`, java throws an error because the file isn't there.

Just before there is a comment who precises that it clears the directory.

Does anyone use the mlunitTest without this problem?
it's the same if i give the name of the result directory with the parameter : `-PunitTestResultsPath=testML`

Here are the traces of this part of execution :

```
Done running all suites; time: 82ms

4 tests completed, 0 failed
Deleted existing results directory: build\test-results\marklogic-unit-test
Releasing connection
:mlUnitTest (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.093 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mlUnitTest'.
> java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: build\test-results\marklogic-unit-test\TEST-historicId.xml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try release 4.3.0 - it includes the following fix - https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/issues/599

Comment: Thank you, it's ok with this version, I've try with different version of Java and OS, and I found a combinaison who was OK : Centos and Java _8, but with the 4.3.0 version of ml-graddle, it's Ok on windows too with java 8